# How do I Bind 2 controls to 1 field AND also access the 2 control values for ConvertBack?

Tags: wpf, binding, datatemplate, ivalueconverter, imultivalueconverter

In a DataGridTemplateColumn DataTemplate,
I want to bind 2 controls to a string field of format "[name]:[value]" i.e. the string is delimited by colon ":". I need to bind control a) to the [name] part and control b) the value part.

I have been able to successfully use an IValueConverter to split the string for display:

```
public class NameAndValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string rtn = ""; 

        string[] split = value.ToString().Split(':');

        if (split.Count() == 2)
        {
            if(parameter.ToString() == "Name")
                rtn = split[0];

            if(parameter.ToString() == "Value")
                rtn = split[1];
        }

        return rtn;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("NameAndValueConverter can only be used OneWay.");
    }
}
```

And the XAML:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <StackPanel.Resources>
                <local:NameAndValueConverter x:Key="NameAndValueConverter" />
            </StackPanel.Resources>
            <TextBox x:Name="namePart" Text="{Binding Path=FieldType, Converter={StaticResource NameAndValueConverter}, ConverterParameter='Name'}" />
            <TextBox x:Name="valuePart" Text="{Binding Path=FieldType, Converter={StaticResource NameAndValueConverter}, ConverterParameter='Value'}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
```

But the data may be edited in the Textboxes so how can I access the 2 TextBox values in ConvertBack so that they can be joined again?

Comment: Do you have access to the viewmodel that you're binding to? Can you introduce 2 new properties to that viewmodel?

Answer (score 1):

Doing this in the XAML:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <StackPanel.Resources>
                <local:NameAndValueConverter x:Key="NameAndValueConverter" />
            </StackPanel.Resources>
            <TextBox x:Name="namePart" Text="{Binding Path=FieldType, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource NameAndValueConverter}, ConverterParameter='Name'}" />
            <TextBox x:Name="valuePart" Text="{Binding Path=FieldType, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource NameAndValueConverter}, ConverterParameter='Value'}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
```

should be enough. You need a `TwoWay` binding to edit from UI, and when you set `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `PropertyChanged` the `TextBox` will update itself automatically when the property will be modified in the ViewModel (you'd obviously need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` )